# "keydown" and "change" events not working for jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, onchange, keydown

I have an input field in each row of my jquery datatable. I have to trigger an event on text change and enter press for each of these input fields.Am loading jquery datatable using serverside processing.Before without using the server side processing the input field events were working fine!.What causes the event to be silent now?

Events i used before ---

```
$('#txtQty').keydown(function (e) {
        alert("keydown");
}

$('#txtQty').change(function () {
         alert("Change");

}
```

same listeners i use after the serverside processing applied.

Jquery grid details-
client side processing and adding input box~

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 <tr>
                    .
.
.
.
.
.
@if (item.Qty <= 0)
{
 <td>
     <input class="inputs" id="txtQty" type="text" value=@item.MinQty />
     </td>
    }
  }
```

Serverside processing and input box applied on the go-

```
$('#grid').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "../myaction/AjaxHandler",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "scrollY": 385,
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "jQueryUI": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sDom": 'lfrtip',

        "aoColumns": [
                        { "sName": "dfgdfg" },
                        { "sName": "dfgdfg" },
                        { "sName": "hhh" },
                        {
                            "sName": "Qty",

                            "mRender": function (sName) {

                                return '<input class="inputs" id="txtQty" type="text"  value='+ sName +' />';
                            },
                        },
                        { "sName": "Category" },
                        { "sName": "Comment" }
        ],
        "oLanguage": {

            "sProcessing":'Processing.....'
        }

    });
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with same ID `txtQty`, don't you? If so, replace `$('#txtQty').keydown` with, for example, `$('.inputs').keydown`

Comment: @Regent tried it didnt work!!

Comment: Due to dynamically created elements use `$(document).on('keydown', '.inputs', function(e)` instead.

Comment: @Regent please add above comment as answer let me say that's the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you have multiple elements with same id `txtQty`. For correct event handling of multiple elements you can use class. For example, class `inputs`.
- for dynamically created elements you can use `$(document).on("event", "selector", function() {});`.

So, finally, it should look like:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.inputs', function(e) {
    alert("keydown");
}

$(document).on('change', '.inputs', function() {
    alert("Change");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there are more than one "txtQty" per page so instead of an id, use a class

```
 <input class="inputs txtQty" type="text" value=@item.MinQty />
```

```
$('.txtQty').keydown(function (e) {
    alert("keydown");
}

$('.txtQty').change(function () {
     alert("Change");
}
```

Comment: no id required? why two classes? class="inputs txtQty"

Comment: this works on client side processing only for datatble in this case!!